# Need to pass alue from JS -> Java -> JS (without JSP change)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

My question evolves java and javascript.

Some point of my program i need to:

1) @Javascript page (.js) i need to get the result of a query

- Only on this page i can get an set of values and i need to pass to that query in the java file

2) @Java after receive the value i need to pass the result to the same .js

3) the jsp page only call the function/page js

- I can't change anything on jsp so that's my BIG problem

Resume: I have to pass a value from js (the only source to get this value) into a query in Java file, and then the same js receive the result of that query. I can't change jsp or make another jsp.

I know is difficult but anyone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can create [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) call(using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [prototype](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/), XMLHttpRequest, whatever best fits existing structure), with request to desired servlet, and from servlet you can parse you query using `request.getParameter(String s)`, after doing what you want with that query, you can send response back using `response.getWriter().write(String s)` and do what you want to do with response in javascript function

Comment: i'm trying XMLHttpRequest and my problem now is to send to the java file. What is the URL to my own file in the project? Is there a way to know?

Comment: You should use servlets to handle this and servlet will be mapped to desired url